# I need help creating a query on sql that

Tags: sql

I have two tables. One that holds employees and one that holds projects. Employee table has a primary key and projects has a foreign key to identify what employee is working on which project. I need to write a query that will return employee's first name and last name but only for those employees that are handling two or more projects. This is what I have so far:

```
create table employee
(
employeeId int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
firstName varChar(25) not null,
lastName varChar(25) not null,
gender varChar(1) not null,
dob date not null,
ssn varChar(9) not null,
)

insert into employee
 values 
    ('Peter','Smith','m','1979-08-25','123112233'),
    ('Juan','Doe','m','1985-05-22','435678907'),
    ('Rafael','Perez','m','1979-03-22','754984568'

create table projects
(
projectId int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
description varChar(100) not null,
status varChar(10) not null,
startDate date not null,
projectedEndDate date not null,
manager int foreign key references employee(employeeId)
```

)

```
insert into projects
values ('this project will improve the power on certain devices','active','2014-09-12','2015-0101','1'),
   ('this project will improve the user interface','active','2014-09-12','2015-01-01','1'),
   ('this project will improve the load time','active','2014-09-12','2015-01-01','2'),
   ('this project will implement stronger security','active','2014-09-12','2015-01-01','2')

   select firstname +' '+ lastname as fullname 
   from projects 
   inner join employee 
   on employee.employeeid = projects.manager
```

which returns

```
Peter Smith
Peter Smith
Juan Doe
Juan Doe
Rafael Perez
```

I've read to use count but haven't been able to implement the join with the count, been stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `group by` and a `having` clause:

```
select firstname +' '+ lastname as fullname 
from projects inner join
     employee 
     on employee.employeeid = projects.manager 
group by firstname +' '+ lastname
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always wrap you SQL:

```
SELECT fullname FROM (
   select firstname +' '+ lastname as fullname 
   from projects 
   inner join employee 
   on employee.employeeid = projects.manager ) t
GROUP BY fullname
HAVING COUNT(distinct projectId) > 1
```